# Multiple Lists in CSV Python with np.savetxt

Tags: python, csv

I try to detect the orientation of colored objects.
I extracted the color and the intensity profile.
color = scalar
int_prof = [11,...,11]

I want to save now multiple lists and the corresponding color value into a single csv.

Each list should now be one column and the color val should be converted to a string and should name my column.
Therefore I wrote a method using pandas dataframe.

The error: The referenceLines are correctly saved in the list
But in csv I get increasing numbers. Can anybody give me a hint where the mistake hides?
      data = {}

> ```
> def saveReferences(self,referenceLines,center,container):
>     print(referenceLines)
>     for i in range(len(container.colors)):
>         self.data.update({str(container.colors[i]):referenceLines[i]})
>     df = pd.DataFrame(self.data)   
>     df.to_csv("foo.csv")
>     print("Save References")
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
>     def saveReferences(self,referenceLines,center,container):
        print(self.referenceProfiles)
        for i in range(len(self.colors)):
            print("saving:",i)
            for num in range(container.saftyFaktor):
                self.data.update({"Color_"+str(self.colors[i])+"_Number_"+str(num):self.referenceProfiles[i+num]})
        df = pd.DataFrame(self.data)   
        df.to_csv("foo.csv",";")
        print(self.data)
        print("Save References")
The code solves the problem!
```